# How to erase local files from webrick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I am building my first application (property management system), and have a lot of partial files locally--things like properties without pictures and descriptions, because when working I did not always fill in all the fields.

Anyways, I'm pretty sure I can go into rails console and delete these files, but not exactly sure how.  Any guidance would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. .  . I went into the DB Browser for SQLite and just deleted the rows.